How to block urls while using selenium with mitmproxy?
I am following this tutorial (https://scrapfly.io/blog/how-to-block-resources-in-selenium/#:~:text=How%20to%20block%20resources%20in%20Selenium%20and%20Python%3F) to block url resources using mitmproxy. It looks like I have block the resources but there are still number of urls which is not working as per expected.
Urls such as
gvt1.com, statically.io, jsdelivr.net, gstatic.com, easylist.to and so on.
# block.py
from mitmproxy import http

# we can block popular 3rd party resources like tracking and advertisements.
BLOCK_RESOURCE_NAMES = [
  'adzerk',
  'analytics',
  'cdn.api.twitter',
  'doubleclick',
  'exelator',
  'facebook',
  'fontawesome',
  'google',
  'google-analytics',
  'googletagmanager',
  # or something abstract like images
  'images',
  'gvt1'
]
# or block based on resource extension
BLOCK_RESOURCE_EXTENSIONS = [
    '.gif',
    '.jpg',
    '.jpeg',
    '.png',
    '.webp',
    '.com'
]

# this will handle all requests going through proxy:
def request(flow: http.HTTPFlow) -> None:
    url = flow.request.pretty_url
    has_blocked_extension = any(url.endswith(ext) for ext in BLOCK_RESOURCE_EXTENSIONS)
    contains_blocked_key = any(block in url for block in BLOCK_RESOURCE_NAMES)
    if has_blocked_extension or contains_blocked_key:
        print(f"Blocked {url}")
        flow.response = http.Response.make(
            404,  # status code
            b"Blocked",  # content
            {"Content-Type": "text/html"}  # headers
        )

And I have used this information to connect other proxy with mitmproxy
How do I connect mitmproxy to another proxy outside of my control?
mitmproxy --mode upstream:https://HOSTNAME:PORT --upstream-auth USER:PASSWORD

Is there a way to block the resources while using mitmproxy with selenium?
Main File
    # I want to have following flow

#python_main_file -> mitmproxy(if we can block all the resources here, so that
# it won't pass to other proxy) -> otherproxy -> webpage and flow back the same pattern

from selenium import webdriver
import subprocess 

command = f"mitmdump -s block.py --mode upstream:https://HOSTNAME:PORT --upstream-auth USER:PASSWORD"
subprocess.Popen(command, shell=True)

PROXY = "localhost:8080"  # IP:PORT or HOST:PORT of our mitmproxy

chrome_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
# this command enabled proxy for our Selenium browser:
chrome_options.add_argument('--proxy-server=%s' % PROXY)

chrome = webdriver.Chrome(options=chrome_options)
# test it by going to a page with blocked resources:
# chrome.get("https://web-scraping.dev/product/1")
chrome.get("https://www.whatsmyip.org/")
chrome.quit()


Please do not link to external sites only, instead post your mitmproxy code you use for blocking, then we can see why it doesn't work as you expect. Please also post the full command you use for starting mitmproxy.

Hi @Robert Thank you for the information. I have attached the code.
Thank You!
